# GeoNear with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**How do I query the model for geoNear with maxDistance of 1km?**

This is my mongoose schema -

```
var userDestinationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    uid: String,                
    update_time: Date,          

    location:{                  //<INDEXED as 2d>
        lon: Number,
        lat: Number
    }
});



var userDestinationModel = mongoose.model('userDestinationModel', userDestinationSchema);
```

I tried doing this and it ain't working.

```
userDestinationModel.geoNear([parseInt(req.params.lon,10),parseInt(req.params.lat,10)],
              { maxDistance : 1, spherical : true }, 
              function(err, results, stats) {
                   console.log(results);
                });
```

**but when I remove** `spherical : true` **it works.**

What is the unit of maxDistance? **//Answer**: **Radian** in case of Legacy Coordinate.

DataSample:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("52f89d8cdbe6f9ea80344fd9"), location: { lon: 165, lat: 165 }, uid: "testuser2", update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T09:36:12.705Z") }
{ _id: ObjectId("52f89d97dbe6f9ea80344fda"), location: { lon: 166, lat: 166 }, uid: "testuser3", update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T09:36:23.236Z") }
{ _id: ObjectId("52f8a16edbe6f9ea80344fdb"), location: { lon: 164, lat: 164 }, uid: "testuser4", update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T09:52:46.464Z") }
{ _id: ObjectId("52f8a173dbe6f9ea80344fdc"), location: { lon: 164, lat: 164 }, uid: "testuser1", update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T09:52:51.125Z") }
{ _id: ObjectId("52f8a17fdbe6f9ea80344fdd"), location: { lon: 165, lat: 165 }, uid: "testuser7", update_time: ISODate("2014-02-10T09:53:03.365Z") }
```

Answer (score 2):

The unit is metres, so you might not be getting correct answer.
For km specify `50*1000`

And perhaps you need to edit your querying document according to this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/

`{ near: POINT_COORDINATES.....`

Comment: still no results. and I am using mongoose.

Comment: Please cehck the question. I have updated it with the sample data.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.geoNear

Comment: I am using legacy coordinate, so the distance is in radian.